# Customization of serialization policy spring-data-mongodb without using annotations

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I want to customize / configure the serialization policy of spring-data-mongodb (version 1.1.1.RELEASE) *without* using annotations (like @Id, @Document, @Field) because I do not have access to the domain classes.

Is this possible? If yes, what is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

In order to customize class serialization as far as I know the only thing you can do is to define custom converters for each class which is described in [reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#mongo.custom-converters)

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind to have a Read- and a WriteConverter for each of your domain classes. Missing the WriteConverter might lead to unexpected content in MongoDB which is not readable by your custom ReadConverter.

ReadConverter should be annotated with `@ReadingConverter` and WriteConverter should be annotated with `@WritingConverter`.